# Jenkins-Maven build failed: Could not find the main class: jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main. Program will exit

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-3

My Jenkins build is failing since a couple of days ago. When I compare the previous success build, I found that `maven32-agent-1.8.1.jar` updated to `maven32-agent-1.12-alpha-1.jar` similarly `maven3-interceptor-commons-1.8.1.jar` to `maven3-interceptor-commons-1.12-alpha-1.jar`.

JDK : `JDK_6u45`

Maven : `3.2.3`

The error I get now is :

```
xx/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK_6u45/bin/java -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -cp /usr01/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven32-agent-1.12-alpha-1.jar:/usr01/app/apache-maven-3.2.3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar:/usr01/app/apache-maven-3.2.3/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main /usr01/app/apache-maven-3.2.3 /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-3.14.jar /usr01/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven32-interceptor-1.12-alpha-1.jar /usr01/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.12-alpha-1.jar 85426
Could not find the main class: jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven32Main.  Program will exit.
ERROR: Failed to launch Maven. Exit code = 1
Started calculate disk usage of build
Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
Started calculate disk usage of workspace
Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
Finished: FAILURE
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: Under which JDK version does your Jenkins run?

Comment: @khmarbaise      it is  2.89.2